# Does our existence cost us energy?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, waves

When something needs to inform its presence, such as the electromagnetic presence of charged particles , or the gravitational presence of particles due to their mass. Is this made by sending information of its existence propagated in space via some kind of electromagnetic waves or hypothesised gravitational waves.

So as a part of telling others of their presence to others, do the particles constantly lose their energy ? I understand that they could also gain energy in same way, but if a particle was completely isolated would it lose its existence and turn into pure energy over time ?

I understand that the mass and energy would together remain constant, but my question is that whether something would happen to a particle or would it remain a particle ?

Comment: Notice that if particles lost energy, they would disappear.

Comment: So how do particles express their fields to fellow particles ? I believe em waves is the way to go and those are costly, I mean energetically.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Are you really asking if there exists a stable elementary particle?

Comment: @ Qmechanic : no I am talking about fields and propogation related energy of all particles which lead me to think of that question

Comment: I think the OP may be asking : If the EM force is communicated by photons (equivalently, if it takes energy to sustain the EM field around an isolated charge), then why don't charged particles lose energy - and therefore mass?  Shouldn't an isolated charge radiate all its mass-energy away?

Answer (score 4):

Energy in physics takes [many forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy#Forms_of_energy), that can be interchangeable during interactions. The law of conservation of energy holds for a summation of all the different energy manifestations of the system under study.

> if a particle was completely isolated would it lose its existence and turn into pure energy over time ?

No . An isolated particle can have energy as its rest mass, can have kinetic energy if it is moving with respect to some coordinate system. There is no way to transfer its rest mass energy anywhere,  unless through interactions ( and then it is not isolated) . An isolated particle is stable if it cannot decay to other particles. The electron for example, or a photon, can only disappear through interactions with other elementary particles.

You are probably confused by the simplified quantum mechanical picture of a charged particle continually exchanging virtual photons with other charged particles in the environment. Virtual photons are a useful calculational tool in getting the probabilities for the interactions of elementary particles. The virtual means that they do not conserve the energy momentum measure of their four vector, they are off mass shell, so energy conservation has no meaning in these exchanges.

In classical electromagnetism the fields of charged particles are stable, they do have an [energy density](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html) but it is associated with the particle as its charge, and cannot be diminished by interactions. This is an observational fact. The boundary conditions of a problem with many charges will determine the composite fields, and any energy produced or lost comes from another form of energy than the field energy density of the individual electrons; it will probably be kinetic or potential energy to start with.

Macroscopically looking at live organisms, yes they continually exchange energy signals with the environment, energy which they have to replenish from other forms ( food).

Not elementary particles though

Comment: So when we charge something (initially uncharged) the charged body does not send electromagnetic waves to establish its field ? I am not sure that this is a correct explanation

Comment: A charged body is either all positive or all negative. If all positive the charge is built up by the elementary charges residing in the ions of the surface. If negative it it the collective field of the electrons residing on the surface. In the process of charging there exist electromagnetic waves because changes in electric or magnetic field generate electromagnetic waves, but it is not the waves that establish the field. The energy for orienting all electrons on the surface comes from the current spent and ultimately from the generators that create the current.

Comment: The static field energy is coming from the combined/collective  field of the electrons.(or ions if it is a positive charge).

Comment: And where is that field coming from (the collective field)?

Comment: @annav It appears, you have not finished your last sentence of the answer.

Comment: Each electron has a charge value of e that creates an electric field around it. A conglomerate  of electrons have a vectorially additive  collective field. It comes from the individual electrons that can never lose their charge e.

Comment: I am not denying that, but since we are taught that those fields are set up not just present as in case of neutron converting to proton and electron, their fields would be set up not just present already, just because they are standing/stationary waves that does not mean thay particles must not be being emitted/exchanged

Comment: Emitting and exchanging particles for non elementary particles, but there exist elementary particles that do not change  their rest-mass, charge and spin, because they are not composite  . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg . All others are built up by these elementary ones in the table, and charges, which make up the composite particles are added and their fields are added vectorially according to the geometry if they are bigger molecules/ coglomarates. This is because charge is an elementary attribute, does not change.(experimental fact)

Comment: You are confused by the virtual particle exchanges in Feynman diagrams. Energy is conserved there only between incoming and outgoing lines. The naming of the intermediate particle lines  are just to keep track of the quantum numbers, As energy is not conserved in the intermediate steps, no energy  is lost by the non interacting static particle, if we assume it is interacting at infinity with another electron.

Comment: But we have never made experiments with isolated systems, which are frankly non-existent. I clearly state in my question that the particles could be gaining back their energy by interaction from other particles. But in an isolated system due to the emission of virtual particles ( guage bosons ) if I am correct in hypothesising that they are emitted for lonely particles too, would drain the particle of its energy and make it nonexistent

Comment: You are not correct in assuming that virtual particles are emitted by isolated particles and lost to infinity. Virtual particle by construction and definition can only exist in the middle of incoming and outgoing lines. Once a photon is real, it has taken from the kinetic energy of the system, not from the energy density of the charge of the electron.

Comment: Well we have been taught (dont know by how much accuracy) that fields like electric field are not just present everywhere, they are established and take finite time to do so; we have also been told that these fields are established with the help of electromagnetic fields so that I believe must be draining the energy of a particle maybe with rate far exceeding that which may result in time more than age of universe, but depleting at the same time. But all I am hearing here is that those fields are just present, simply present.

Comment: Well, this site cannot give a course on classical and quantum electrodynamics in a question and answer way. It takes years to build up the background in mathematics and physics to understand these subjects. Again, the intrinsic fields are identified with elementary particles and no energy exchange happens in the field of the particles. An ensemble of particles has a collective behavior, but any energy lost or gained collectively will come from other forms of energy and not from the intrinsic field energy of the elementary constituents.

Comment: Just to complete my understanding, so in setting up electric fields, gravitational fields, etc for a particle no energy is required and some other phenomenon than what I said takes place, correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is not a phenomenon it is a descriptive mathematical model of what we have found experimentally, that charges and masses at an elementary level are very specific and unchangeable  . We have found the field description that is consistent both for point sources and for ensembles of point sources with maxwells equations for electromagnetism. Newtons equations for gravity  from  observations, and theorists are working on a consistent view of General relativity ( validated experimentally by astrophysical measurements) and particle field theory.

Answer (score 2):

> Anything when it needs to inform its presense such as electromagnetic presense of charged particles and gravitational presense of particles due to their mass does so by sending information of its existencs propogated in space via means of electromagnetic waves or hypothesised gravitational waves.

Not true. Maxwell's equations have wave solutions and static solutions. They are two different things. Similarly, the Einstein field equations have wave solutions and static solutions, and they're different things.

> So as a part of telling others of their presense to others, do the particles constantly lose their enegy ?

No. Static fields don't transport energy.

Comment: So would you say that when a neutron turns into a proton and electron their electric fields are just set up in 0 time, and then are set up forever ? Since they are static. I mean in negligible time I understand, but you are saying because maxwells equations give static waves, they are already there ? That is surely wrong !!

Comment: @rijulgupta: In your example, the electric dipole moment D is zero before the neutron decays, and then after the decay it begins to attain nonzero values. This causes a change in the field, which propagates outward as a wave. This is not a static example, since D is time-varying.

Comment: And your point is ? I am simply talking about emission of information(of field) with energy, as informtion wouls travel via waves having energy, I go back to my question